# Attaching a C/C++ thread to a socket

Tags: c++, function, sockets, pthreads

My code, which is taken from on-line sources looks like below:

```
//.. initialization and other things..
int connfd = 0;
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address,&client_address_len);
//... other code
 pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &foo, &connfd);
```

The code above, will call the function foo with argument id. Now each thread will have its own version of foo to run with the argument. In foo, I am able to send data to a client using the socket. However, I am failing to see how (although it works perfectly fine), what is linking the thread and the socket. I understand that id is passed, but it that is only an integer.

This is what the foo function looks like:

```
  void* SendFileToClient(void *var){
   int *connfd;
   connfd =(int*) var;
   std::cout << "Connection accepted and id:" << *connfd << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Connected to Client with IP: " <<   inet_ntoa(c_addr.sin_addr) << "Port:" << ntohs(c_addr.sin_port) << std::endl; // inet_ntoa converts binary form of IPv4 to IPv4 dotted numbers, ntohs does something silimar for ports
   int write_size = write(*connfd, fname,64);

   std::cout << write_size << "connfds: " <<  *connfd << std::endl;

   FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"rb");

   if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("File opern error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Read data from file and send it */
    while(1)
    {
        /* First read file in chunks of 64 bytes */
        unsigned char buff[1024]={0};
        int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);

        /* If read was success, send data. */
        if(nread > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Sending..." << std::endl;
            write_size =  write(*connfd, buff, nread);
        }
        if (nread < 1024)
        {
            if (feof(fp)) //end of file indicator
            {
                std::cout << "End of file" << std::endl;
                std::cout << "File transfer completed for id:" << *connfd << std::endl;
            }
            if (ferror(fp))
                std::cout << "Error reading" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Closing Connection for id:" << *connfd << std::endl;
    close(*connfd);
    shutdown(*connfd,SHUT_WR);
    sleep(2);
    return NULL;
```

}

In the code above, the call to

```
   write(*connfd, buff, nread);
```

knows to send data through a socket referenced by connfd.

Comment: If you are voting down please indicate what is wrong as to help others and myself get something out of the negation.

Comment: What do you mean by "linking the thread and the socket"?

Comment: There is no link, not really. As far as the thread's concerned it's going to call a function and pass it a value that just happens to be used by the function as an `int` and that `int` just happens to be a socket identifier.

Comment: As in the thread if you make a call such as: write(*id, buff, nread); it gets that it has to send it through the connection it just accepted

Comment: A description of `pthread_create` can be found in `man` pages such as http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html.

Comment: I've read the man page but it doesn't really answer my question, I will add the foo function for clarity

Comment: `id = accept(...)` `pthread_create(..., &id)`

Comment: I added the function, the replaced id by connfd.

Comment: Not seeing the rest of the code (because it isn't posted), the biggest concern I have is the lifetime of `id`. If it is in some do-while iteration accepting connections, it will fall out of scope with each iteration. A thread that is holding it's address as a passed argument may not have acquired the referenced `int` value prior to that, leaving you in the land of UB when you finally do. This can be incredibly subtle, as it can easily appear to "work". Only when a raft of connections are inbound and the data begins being overwritten in `id` will things start looking odd.

Comment: `int *connfd; connfd =(int*) var;`. You should not do this. You should *copy* the FD as quickly as possible: `int connfd = *(int*)var;`. Otherwise it will change after the next accept.

Comment: @WhozCraig Are you saying that in the while loop, id's of sockets and the thread handling them can get mixed up?

Comment: @EJP: I will try that. Thank you

Comment: You are deferencing `*connfd` every time  you use it. If `accept()` has returned again, it will have returned a different FD, and your thread will now be using the wrong FD; and you will have lost the original FD; so you will also have a socket leak.

Comment: @hadis Easily. One solution that will not take much to turn out is to push the connection descriptor through an `intptr_t`. There's a fair amount of casting involved there, however, and one can easily get confused, even though the code would be standard-compliant. Another solution is to simply dynamically allocate an `int` and store the accepted connection in that, then  pass it as the user-arg to pthread_create. Finally, let the thread proc close the descriptor and free the memory. Either of these approaches will not simply minimize the race condition, it will *eliminate* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is linking the thread and the socket

`connfd`. It is the file descriptor for the socket. Yes, it is "only an integer", but your operating system (which handles all the socket-related function calls) knows what to do with it, and performs all the necessary mappings for you. That's why it gave you that value as a result from the `accept` call: as a handle to use with future socket function calls.

As mentioned elsewhere, do note that you are currently passing `connfd` to the thread unsafely; you should instead pass in a copy … either encoded into the thread argument, masquerading as a pointer (via `uintptr_t`) or in some fresh dynamically-allocated object to which you can then pass a pointer into the thread.

Or, ideally, drop pthreads and use `std::thread`, since it is now 2018 already and that facility has been available for quite some time. This allows for very expressive passing of as many arguments as you want to `foo`, so you'd just pass `connfd` by value and leave it at that.

Comment: @EJP: I am talking about the original `int`. We can remove mentions of variable names if it's clearer - the key point is that the FD is responsible.

Comment: Well my point is that he *didn't* pass it to the thread. He passed its *address,* which is the problem.

Comment: @EJP: While I certainly don't dispute that there is a problem, the question doesn't ask about a problem. It asks what links the thread and the socket. That's what I am addressing (no pun intended)

Comment: @EJP: What would be the correct way to go about this? I didn't really write the code, I found it online as a starting point.

Comment: @hadis Refer to the comments under EJP's answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you picture threads incorrectly. A thread is just a way to call and execute your function. The program calls the `foo` function, but allows it to run in somewhat concurrent way, sharing execution time (and multiple cpus, if you have them) with other calls to the same or to a different function. This manner of execution is the thread and it is managed by the OS, similarly to other processes.

Your program just calls a regular function 'foo' and passes an argument, which happens to be the `confd` file descriptor. This is the only thing the `foo` function needs to know about the socket in order to write data into it. The program also tells operating system that it wants to execute this function as a thread, by calling pthread_create. The function itself does not care how it gets executed.

When the function exits, operating system stops the thread execution.

So, there is no really any link between socket and a thread. Just the function...

Answer (score 0):

The `write` function doesn't care whether the handle maps to a socket, a file or a laser gun, it only knows how to write content into a buffer and signal that the buffer is ready to be flushed.  How it gets flushed was arranged when you created the socket, opened the file or the laser gun.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *connfd;
connfd =(int*) var;
```

You should not do this. You must *copy* the FD as quickly as possible:

```
int connfd = *(int*)var;
```

Otherwise it will change after the next accept. You are deferencing `*connfd` every time  you use it. If `accept()` has returned again, it will have returned a different FD, and your thread will now be using the wrong FD; and you will have lost the original FD; so you will also have a socket leak.

Better still, pass it in a piece of dynamic memory that the thread is responsible for freeing.

Comment: While you're right, I don't really think "copy the FD as quickly as possible" is sufficient unless you're protecting the original `connfd` somehow. Instead, pass a copy into the thread to begin with.

Comment: Ok you did allude to that at the end to be fair

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I would concur with that. A conversion from `int` to `intptr_t`, then cast to `void*`, then undo all of that it on the thread-proc, would be one way. Another no-cast solution is the dynamic allocate, store, launch, and thread-free, approach. Either will solve the existing race condition.

Comment: @WhozCraig The `intptr_t` varaible will have the same liveness problems as the original FD, surely? It's right next to it on the stack.

Comment: @EJP No, no.. it's passed by *value*., cast to `void*`. Basically, you stuff the descriptor into a pointer, then unstuff it on the thread side; not point to the descriptor with a pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig I do not understand. You need to post the code for this.

Comment: @EJP: If you're stuck with a `void*` then `pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &foo, (void*)(uintptr_t)connfd);` (ish). On the other end it's `const int connfd = (uintptr_t)theVoidPtr;` (ish)

Comment: Of course this is C++ so the OP should simply use `std::thread` and pass by value.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, *yeah*, no kidding =P

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @jwdonahue No, but it answers the next one. I don't think the question that was asked can be answered properly. It's based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @user4581301: I don't see any misunderstanding. OP just can't believe that "only an integer" (the FD) can allow POSIX function calls from different threads to apparently magically affect the same socket. Of course the answer is that the FD is a handle given to us by the OS which does all the clever lookups for us.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Right on, that is was my exact issue.